# Using Quarto in Blogdown

Tags: r, quarto

I would like to use the quarto markdown format for rendering blog posts in R's `blogdown` package, however am struggling to get blogdown/hugo to notice the output `index.md` or `index.html` files that constitute blog posts.

I found [this](https://www.apreshill.com/blog/2022-04-we-dont-talk-about-quarto/#what-youll-stumble-on) post which mentions the post itself is a quarto doc used in blogdown, but I'm unable to recreate the steps.

So far I render the quarto document which outputs `index.html` in the post directory but after `blogdown::build_site` and launching the server, no dice. Not even a mal-formed post being rendered.

Comment: See this discussion about blogdown and quarto (https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/463#discussioncomment-2508252) - Migrating from Rmd to Qmd has no really advantage as you can't really use Quarto feature in a Hugo website, or at least it will be limited. 
See also quarto hugo format (https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/hugo.html) that should work with Hugo directly. 
Please open an issue in blogdown github repo with an example if you think there is an issue with the package when .md or .html file are rendered